# Email Validation RegEx username/local name length check not running

Tags: javascript, regex

I've debugged for a few hours now and have hit a wall - regex has never been my strongsuit. I have been able to alter the following regex to restrict 255 characters for domain fine, however, in trying to restrict the local/username portion of an email address I'm running into issues implementing a 64 character limit. I've gone through regex101 replacing +s and *s and attempting to understand what each pass is doing - however, even when I add a check against all non-whitespace characters with a limit of 64 it seems like the other checks pass and take precedence - although I'm not sure. Below is my regex currently without any of the 64 character checks that I've broken it with:

```js
var emailCheck = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.{0,1}([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){1,255}([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){1,255}([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.*$/i);
```

What I have so far can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/mtqx0tz1/ , I've made other slight alterations (e.g. not allowing consecutive dots) but for the most part this regex comes from another stack post without the character limits.

Lastly, I'm aware this isn't the 'standard' so to speak and emails are checked server-side, however, I would like to be more safe than sorry...as well as work on some of my regex. Sorry if this question isn't worthy of an actual post - I'm just simply not seeing where in my passes {1,64} is failing. At this point I'm thinking about just sub-stringing the portion of the string up to the @ sign and checking length that way...but it would be nice to include it in this statement since all the checks are done here to begin with.

Comment: What the hell is that thing? Also, why are you using `/.../` to create a regex object, then passing it to `new RegExp()`, creating another regex object?

Comment: Why are you trying to cram all kinds of checks into a single regex?

Comment: Sort of just what I found haha - no real reason why it's the Frankenstein it is today :p
Edit: Good call on the new RegExp() - you can see my novice showing when it comes to regex haha. Anyway, the reason for the all the character checks and weird escapes is because this 'page' is run through a templating engine which does not like seeing stuff such as $ anywhere, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I have used this regex validation and it works good.
The e-mail address is in the variable strIn

```
try
            {
                return Regex.IsMatch(strIn,
                      @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
                      @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
            }
            catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: That allows invalid hostnames such as `[999.999.999.999]` or `a__b.01`. Also, wrong programming language.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but what is in place server side is fine and working as it should...in any case the servlet is Java :p. This is specifically more a front-end issue.